# Error While create new angular project with ng

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Iam new at angular While Trying to execute this command 
`ng new my-dream-app`

I got The error below

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>
```

Full screen of error details

[image: Full screen of error details]

My npm version 6.14.4
and my Node version v13.13.0
I tried to install and uninstall node and force clean cache and change Node version but all of this not work

Comment: did you try with node 12 ?

Comment: Have you tried the below solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have npm version 5 or above, try this first:

```
$ sudo npm cache verify
```

Otherwise:

```
$ sudo npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: i've tried this solution as i mentioned in question but not working , The error gone with out doing any thing don't know why